# Scala infix notation for generics

Tags: scala, dsl, infix-notation

Can generics be used in Scala infix notations?

For example:

```
// Example from play-json

Json.obj("name" -> "Joe") \ "name" as[String] // Generics in infix notation
                                              // error: type application is not allowed for postfix operators
```

Ideally, I would like to achieve API like:

```
Json.obj("name" -> "Joe") \ "name" as String // But I think its implossible
```

Of course, using standard dot notation with parentheses it works fine:

```
(Json.obj("name" -> "Joe") \ "name").as[String]
```

The only worthy discussion that I found: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalatest-users/Ujn2d2MdXm0/yvHpk1pOlDMJ

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233227/scala-infix-vs-dot-notation

Answer (score 0):

Infix notation can only be used for parenthesis not the square brackets which capture the type information. If you give the type hint on LHS, then it can be dropped.